# Making .exe installer from Netbeans 6.9.1

Tags: java, netbeans, exe

I'm getting familiar with the Netbeans IDE further.
And when I searched how to create a installer (*.exe) for an application, I found a tutorial on youtube [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZJf10Xq_Td4).
Yet when I tried the instructions on Windows 7. I can't find the installer selection on the project properties.

How can I create a *.exe installer and a *.exe program of the application using Netbeans or other program.

Comment: A plugin you need to install?

Comment: No. I just got interested about the installers and (*.exe) on the Task Manager.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are developing a NetBeans platform application, simply right click on the project and choose "Build Installers"

If your project is not based on the NetBeans platform you need to use an external installer builder like IzPack: http://izpack.org/ or NSIS (http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page)

Comment: Then the output of the package would still be *.jar ?

Comment: @Cyril: The output for the NetBeans Platform application is an .exe installer. I believe the the two installer builders create .exe as well. Why don't you just read through their documentation or try them out?