# NetBeans Installer Plugin

Tags: java, netbeans, installation

I am working in NetBeans IDE 7.1. I was looking for how to create a installer (*.exe) for an application, I found a tutorial [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/generate_a_netbeans_platform_installer), but i couldn't find the installer option in project properties.Where can i download the installer plugin from?

Answer (score 1):

The example that the author presents in the tutorial only works if you create a "NetBeans Platform Application" project (you can find it under New Project->NetBeans Modules), which is built based on [NBI](http://wiki.netbeans.org/NBI).

However, this other post ([Making .exe installer from Netbeans 6.9.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5650798/making-exe-installer-from-netbeans-6-9-1)) may help you in achieving your goal.